# SQL - Convert ROW_NUMBER function with multiple order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert this query to a subquery without the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
 SELECT InvestorFundId, AsOfDate, AddedOn FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvestorFundId ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC, AddedOn DESC) AS HistoryIndex, *
                      FROM   [Investor.Fund.History]
                      WHERE  DataStatusId = 1 AND AsOfDate <= (SELECT PeriodDate FROM [Fund.Period] WHERE Id = 5461)
                      ) G WHERE HISTORYINDEX = 1
```

Basically this is selecting the most recent `[Investor.Fund.History]` within a time period and depending on the status.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT InvestorFundId, MAX(AsOfDate) AS MaxAsOfDate, MAX(AddedOn) AS MaxAddedOn FROM [Investor.Fund.History]
WHERE DataStatusId = 1 AND AsOfDate <= (SELECT PeriodDate FROM [Fund.Period] WHERE Id = 5461)
GROUP BY InvestorFundId
```

My query gives the incorrect results and it does this because when i use the `MAX` function on multiple columns, it does not select the max based on the order of both columns like the ROW_NUMBER does, instead it selects the `MAX` no matter both columns order positions.

For example, if I have a subset of data which looks like this:

```
 | InvestorFundId |          AsOfDate       |           AddedOn         |
 |  1             | 2010-10-01 00:00:00.000 |   2012-04-18 09:29:33.277 |
 |  1             | 2006-11-01 00:00:00.000 |   2013-04-18 11:25:23.033 |
```

The ROW_NUMBER function will return the following:

```
  |  1             | 2010-10-01 00:00:00.000 |   2012-04-18 09:29:33.277 |
```

Whereas my function returns this:

```
 |  1             | 2010-10-01 00:00:00.000 |   2013-04-18 11:25:23.033 |
```

Which as you can see, is not actually a row in the table.

I would like my function to correctly return the row in the table based on the `MAX` `AsOfDATE` AND `AddedOn`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Uh... Is there a reason you're looking to change this? Using ROW_NUMBER() is the standard for something like this.

Comment: @ZLK I've just started working at a new company and they want to remove the ROW_NUMBER function and they say that it isn't optimized

Comment: Uh... Like they don't have indexes for it? I'm not sure what `it isn't optimized` means here. Realistically speaking, any query you write is going to have to go through each group and select one row based on criteria. There are instances where things like `APPLY` or gordon's answer below might be faster, but they can also be slower than row_number() sorts.

Comment: @ZLK They do have indexes on the tables, im sure that theres a few which they are missing though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a unique id that identifies each row, then you can do:

```
WITH ifh as (
      SELECT InvestorFundId, AsOfDate, AddedOn
      FROM [Investor.Fund.History]
      WHERE DataStatusId = 1 AND AsOfDate <= (SELECT PeriodDate FROM [Fund.Period] WHERE Id = 5461)
     )
SELECT ifh.*
FROM ifh
WHERE ifh.? = (SELECT ?
               FROM ifh ifh2
               WHERE ifh2.InvestorFundId = ifh.InvestorFundId
               ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC, AddedOn DESC
               FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
              );
```

The `?` is for the column that uniquely identifies each row.

This is also possible to do using `APPLY`:

```
select ifh2.*
from (select distinct InvestorFundId
      from ifh
     ) i cross apply
     (select top (1) ifh2.*
      from ifh ifh2
      where fh2.InvestorFundId = i.InvestorFundId
      order by AsOfDate DESC, AddedOn DESC
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) ifh2;
```

Comment: I dont think the first suggestion is value sql but the second is. Although I just checked and your suggestion uses 99% of the query cost in relation to the batch compared to the original query